# How many ways are there to color each of the dots in the given diagram using red, blue, and/or green?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to color each of the dots in this diagram using red, blue, and/or green such that there are no identical colors right next to each other?

I don't want to do individual counting/casework.

[image]

Found the answer! It is $192$

Comment: It is easiest to start with the 3-way vertex.  How many choices?  Then go down each path.  How many choices for each dot?

Comment: Can't we do it without casework? I am getting feeling of overcounting this way.

Comment: This is not casework.  It counts each dot once.  You may see a pattern so it is even faster.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I didn't understand it when you first said but got it now and found the answer as well, it's $192$

Answer (score 3):

Start from any one of the dots placed at the 2 terminal positions (at the top left or from the extreme right)

It has 3 colour options

Start going progressively to other dots **in the order in which they appear**

For example, the dot adjacent to the 1st dot has 2 colour options (excluding the 1 colour which the terminal dot has selected)

Similarly, all other 6 dots individually have 2 colour options, as they cannot take the colour already chosen by their adjacent dot, which was approached *before them*

The final answer is **2^6 × 3 = 192**

Comment: There are more than $3$ colour options for the first dot. The problem does not say that each dot is to be coloured using "red, blue or green", it says each dot is coloured using "red, blue **and/or** green". So the dot may be coloured red **and** blue, or red **and** green, or blue **and** green. If each dot were supposed to get only one colour they would have said "or" instead of "and/or". What else could the "and" be for?

Comment: I thought that it meant each of the three colours **may or may not** be used

Comment: You may be right. The problem is badly worded. Probably a Google translation.